# Image not rotating

Tags: php

I am trying to rotate image using php imagerotate function but its not working.
GD Library is also on.

i have tried this ,

```
public function rotate()
       {
            $targ_w = 240;
            $targ_h = 180;
            $jpeg_quality = 100;
            $degrees = 90;


           $src = "/photos/sunset.jpg";

           $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);

           $rotatedImage = imagerotate($image,$degrees,0);

           imagejpeg( $rotatedImage,$src,$jpeg_quality);

           imagedestroy($rotatedImage);

            die();
        }
```

Comment: Define _not working_. Any errors in the output?

Comment: NO error checked with error_reporting

Comment: What are dimensions of the new image file (_out.jpg_)?

Comment: Don't you want to output the $rotatedImage in your impagejpeg function?

Comment: where to pass dimension ??

Comment: What version of GD do you have? according to docs: `Note: JPEG support is only available if PHP was compiled against GD-1.8 or later.`

Comment: Off topic, but have you considered skipping all this PHP code, and rotating the image using CSS in the browser instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're outputing the **unchanged** `$image` to file. You should output the rotated one.

```
imagejpeg( $rotatedImage,$name ,$jpeg_quality);
```

The second thing - your image is empty. It has only defined width and height but has no content inside it. You defined a `$src` variable but you don't use it at all.
Maybe you want to replace `imagecreatetruecolor` with this:

```
$src = "/photos/sunset.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
```

Comment: How does the output image look like? Is it 180px wide and 240px tall? And is it completely white or filled with `photos/sunset.jpg`?

Comment: trying to rotate same image in same folder.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Could you strictly answer the questions I asked in the above comment?

Comment: As per you suggest code is working fine.I got the issue in not getting img in $src.

Answer (score 1):

```
      <?php
       // File and rotation
       $filename = 'test.jpg';
       $degrees = 180;
       // Content type
       header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
       // Load
       $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
       // Rotate
       $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
       // Output
       imagejpeg($rotate);
       // Free the memory
       imagedestroy($source);
       imagedestroy($rotate);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must output the rotated image (pass `$rotatedImage` instead of `$image`):

```
$rotatedImage = imagerotate($image,$degrees,0);


header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); //Header is required to output the image.

imagejpeg($rotatedImage,$name ,$jpeg_quality);
imagedestroy($rotatedImage);
die();
```

Comment: You updated the answer but still showing `$image` and not `$rotatedImage` did you change this? `imagejpeg($rotatedImage,$name ,$jpeg_quality);`

Comment: I was almost sure that he update the question.... sorry, my bad. Well, Swap check @matewka answer, looks good

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show the image then you need to change that:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); //Add jpeg header
imagejpeg( $rotatedImage, NULL, 100);  //<-- Notice i remove the $src parameter
```

If you want to update your jpg file then your code will work, but the user that runs the php file need permissions to write the file. Of course your current image will be overwritten.

And as i said in comments you will need GD version 1.8 or later to work with jpeg files according to php.net